# insert form em php Notice: Undefined index: cod_escurcao in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rumos\insertar_hotel.php on line 15

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de curso, al hacer el formulario para registro
me presenta el error:

> Notice: Undefined index:.

Ya intente de todo hasta escribir todo el código de nuevo y sigo con el mismo problema.

```
<?php 

  require 'funcs/conexion.php';
  var_dump($_POST);

  $origem = $_POST['origem'];

  $sql= "INSERT INTO test (origem)  VALUES ($origem) ";
  $resultado= $mysqli->query($sql);

  if($resultado){
    echo "dados salvo com sucesso";
  }else{
    echo "erro ao salvar dados";
  }

?>
```

Y mi `.html` desde donde llamo al `.php` es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="insertar_test.php" method="post">
      <label>origem</label>
      <input type="text" name="origem" id="origem">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloca el error completo ya que el error da pistas de donde esta el problema

Comment: Guarda tu archivo .html como .php para que te funcione

Comment: @J.Correa  ya esta  guardado como .php pero mismo asi sigo con el error pero ahora en todas las lineas del _POST

Comment: creo que la recomendación que te hicieron iba en que el archivo que guarda tu formulario también tenga extensión php

Comment: @Aprendiz si lo hice tengo todos los files en .php.Lo que no entiendo es que tengo otros formularios de insert de datos que si funcionan sin errores.

Comment: @everson Si el error que tira es el que está en el título de la pregunta, no veo el código del `insertar_hotel.php` ni su llamada. Si tu `html` llama al `php` que has puesto ahí, no debería de tirar ese error, porque no hay ninguna llamada con la clave `cod_escurcao`